# Static variable in functions

Tags: php

I saw this on W3Schools.

```
<?php
  function myTest() {
  static $x = 0;
  echo $x;
  $x++;
  }

myTest();
myTest();
myTest();
?>
```

The output is 0, 1 and 2.
I wonder why it is not 0, 0 and 0.
Since each time the function is called, the variable x becomes 0 again.

I am a PHP beginner. Thanks!

Comment: because each time you call the function you reset $x to zero (0).

Comment: Yeah but then why the output is 0, 1, 2?

Comment: `static` is only declared when the function is first called. It's remembered on each subsequent call. That's how `static` works in a function scope. It's basically something to remind us that PHP has its roots in C

Answer (score 2):

If you declare a var static inside a function, the var keep it value over multiple calls. You could compare it to a static var inside of classes.

The code you post is a good example to see the actual effect. However I would only carefull use static inside functions, because most of the time, you need the static value somewhere else, reset the value, or something else which requires to much logic and makes the code really bad.

A good example would be a function, which returns a unique identifier for a given identifier. This could be simply achieved by using this code.

```
function unique_id($id) {
    static $count = 0;
    return $id . ($id++);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example may clarify.  **static** has a **scope**, thus is not a global variable.  So I can define static $x outside the function and it will be defined there.  Since static has scope, it wouldn't make any sense to keep on executing and resetting $x = 0.  So, php will only acknowledge it the first time that line is called.

```
<?php
static $x = 1000;

  function myTest() {
      static $x = 0;
      echo $x;
      $x++;
  }

myTest();
myTest();
myTest();
?>
```